# I can’t hear anyone and they can’t hear me iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, call

My phone won’t let me enable speaker and no one can hear me and I can’t hear anyone else anyone know why? I’m not connected to Bluetooth and the speaker phone has a different colour basically saying u can’t enable it

Comment: Please elaborate, when you tap the speaker button while on a call, what happens? Does the phone respond in any way? What were the steps you took to test if you couldn't be heard? This sounds like something that would happen if e.g. a bluetooth headset device was paired to the phone, but it wouldn't prevent you from enabling the speakerphone.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots so we see the same error etc you do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested the microphone using the Voice Recorder or confirmed the audio works when playing music? If neither of those work, sounds like you've got a hardware fault that needs an Apple diagnosis